# jQuery: function won't be executed until ajax call is complete

Tags: jquery, function, sequence

There's a TinyMCE textarea on my website. When i click the "Save" button, the function save(); is called. It should lock the TinyMCE Editor while saving (assume save.php takes a few seconds to load). Even though formProgress(1) is the first line of code in my save() function, it won't be executed right away. The editor just gets locked for a moment AFTER the ajax call has completed. Anyone know how to fix that?

```
function save()
{
 formProgress(1); //why won't this be executed right away? for some reason i can see the result of this only when the ajax call is complete?!
 jQuery.ajax({
  url: 'save.php',
  type: 'POST',
  data: 'html=' + $('textarea[name=content_html]').tinymce().getContent(),
  completed: function() { formProgress(0); },
  async : false
 });
}

function formProgress(mode)
{
  if(mode == 1)
  {
    $('textarea[name=content_html]').tinymce().setProgressState(1);
  }
  else
  {
    $('textarea[name=content_html]').tinymce().setProgressState(0); 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It *does* complete right away, the issue is here:

```
async : false
```

The way `async: false` works *also* locks up your browser, so although everything before *does* happen before....but your UI is locked up and won't be updated until the XmlHttpRequest completes.

This is one of the main reasons *not* to use `async: false` whenever possible.

Comment: great, thx a lot mate! i changed async to true. however, i had to also change the formProgress(0) function to the "success" event. if i leave it to the "completed" event it somehow won't fire.

Answer (score 0):

the [`setProgressState`](http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE%3aAPI/tinymce.Editor/setProgressState) method accepts as parameter a time delay for appearing.

This implies that it is called with a `setTimeout` so this would explain why it has not yet been shown when the code moves to the next line.. (the ajax call)

Answer (score 0):

Try this function call asynchronously by using settimeout e.g.

```
function save()
{
    setTimeout("formProgress(1)",1000);
    // AJAX call
}
```

Comment: This isn't the issue anyway, but don't pass a string to `setTimeout`, use an anonymous function if you need parameters, just the function name if you need none: `setTimeout(function() { formProgress(1); }, 1000);`